# Using functions as parameters of lambda function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, lambda

Could someone explains to me what happens in this piece of code?

```
g = lambda a,b: (lambda x,y: a(x)*b(y))
z = g(sum,sum)([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
print(z)
```

Hi. I'm quite new to programming. I'm supposed to predict what the result of the code below. I typed it in my editor and 90 was printed. I guess the code sums each list and just multiplied it with each other. Could someone please give an explanation? i just can't understand what's happening. I have used lambda to an extend, but not in this particular way and I know this isn't a good way to type in a function in python. But this was part of a programming class i'm taking and the instructor just wanted to trick us with the syntax, i think..

Comment: `g(sum,sum)([1,2,3],[4,5,6])` -> `sum([1,2,3]) * sum([4,5,6])`.

Comment: Just analyse it by breaking it into parts. `g(sum,sum)` returns `lambda x,y: sum(x)*sum(y)`. And then `([1,2,3],[4,5,6])` are arguments for that

Comment: I've understood now thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0):

It's gonna be much more readable if you factor out the lambdas:

```
def g(a, b):
    def fun(x, y):
        return a(x)*b(y)
    return fun

g_sum = g(sum,sum)
z = g_sum([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
print(z)
```

The above code is functionally the same as the one you posted.

Now we can analyse it step by step to figure out what it's doing.

`g` takes 2 functions and returns another function, let's call it `g_sum`. Since its created with 2 `sum` functions, we'll have `g_sum(x, y) => sum(x)*sum(y)`. If we take arguments passed to `g_sum`, that's `sum([1,2,3]) * sum([4,5,6]) => 6 * 15 => 90`

Answer (score 0):

Let's first point to python lambda expression , aka. anonymous function ( shorthand function ) ,
it's syntax `lambda arguments : expression`.

you specify your desired argument(s) , and only one expression , this argument(s) are function needed parameters while the expression it's execution / evaluation consider this function return.

for the given example , `lambda a,b: (lambda x,y: a(x)*b(y))` , let's analyze it from out to in , first we define a function with arguments a , b and it's return is the execution of another inner function that it's arguments are x , y and it's return is the apply of `a` on x and `b` on y where a , b are the arguments of outer function.

for this `g = lambda a,b: (lambda x,y: a(x)*b(y))`

once we call `g(function1,function2)` , this part returns an object of type function that expects two arguments x , y and will return the execution result of `function1(x)*function2(y)`

N.B , `sum` is reference / name to built-in function in python .

so this `g(sum,sum)([1,2,3],[4,5,6])` , first part of `g(sum,sum)` returns an object let's name it `f` of type `function` that expects two arguments and will return execution result of `sum(x)*sum(y)`.

So expression become as `f([1,2,3],[4,5,6])` , this function receives it's needed two parameters `x = [1,2,3]` and `y = [4,5,6]` then returns `sum([1,2,3])*sum([4,5,6])` that evaluates to `90` and this is the final return from this expression.

so we can break the call as ,

```
g = lambda a,b: (lambda x,y: a(x)*b(y))
f = g(sum,sum) 
z = f([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
print(z)
```

also if we want to expand this lambda to normal functions we can do it as ,

```
def g(a,b):
    def f(x,y):
        return a(x)*b(y)
    return f

f = g(sum,sum) 
z = f([1,2,3],[4,5,6])

# or direct z = g(sum,sum)([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
print(z)
```